# File icon not updated after installation of dreamweaver cs5

Tags: dreamweaver

After I installed Dreamweaver cs5 the php was not associated with it. I changed the default program to open php file to Dreamweaver but even after that the ICON is still comming of notepad. I even tried to change the icon but couldn't locate the Dreamweaver php file icon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any information I can't do much.

I'd try rebuilding your icon cache: http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-rebuild-icon-cache-in-windows-7-to-repair-icons/.